# Can't resolve findPreference() from MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-sharedpreferences

I'm getting a compiler error **cannot resolve method findPreference** when I try to intialize an `OnSharedPreferencesChanged` listener in my MainActivity. According to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646247/android-how-do-i-call-findpreference-from-my-main-activity):

> findPreference() should be called from a class implementing PreferenceActivity interface

but I don't understand what the code to do this would be. How can I get rid of the compiler error and successfully set listeners for preference changes?

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
        private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ...
            //Test preference menu
            listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
                public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
                    if (key.equals("pref_wood")) {
                        Preference woodPref = findPreference(key);  //COMPILER ERROR HERE
                        MainActivity.getGLSurfaceView().setTexture("");
                        // Set summary to be the user-description for the selected value
                        woodPref.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`findPreference` is a method which is part of both `PreferenceFragment` and `PreferenceActivity` - these are the Fragments/Activities that actually show your Preference screen (the activity is deprecated and you should be using the `PreferenceFragment`).

You're trying to use it in your `MainActivity`. This doesn't work because the Preference objects don't actually exist on this screen (they exist in another activity that usually have a `PreferenceFragment` as part of it). If you need to get access to a preference value of a preference in an activity that is not your preference screen, use `SharedPreferences`, something like:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.saved_high_score_default);
boolean wood = sharedPref.getBoolean(pref_wood, defaultValue);
```

You can check out the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) for further examples.

If your `MainActivity` is supposed to be a screen that shows settings, then you should probably rename it and include a preference fragment inside of it.

I believe you're also going to run into trouble with `setSummary` because the `Preference` is not part of this activity, it's part of the activity where you actually modify the preferences. `setSummary` is used to update the actual UI of the `Preference` so that if you, for example, select one of three values when using a list preference, it shows the value you just selected on the screen.

Comment: @Lyla--I appreciate the first paragraph of good info. But "*something like*"?? Your first line doesn't work in an `Activity`. Why not give us something that YOU have used in an actual working program to imitate using `findPreference` in an `Activity`.